Connect to ADW with not ADMIN user in DBeaver
I have already created my ADW. I can connect to it with my ADMIN user (using the wallet) with Dbeaver. The connection configuration looks like this:

I have created a user for other person to connect to the ADW:
-- USER SQL
CREATE USER USER01 IDENTIFIED BY Ab1234567890;

-- ADD ROLES
GRANT CONNECT TO USER01;
GRANT RESOURCE TO USER01;

Now, I would like to test the connection with this user in DBeaver (I am using the same wallet), but I got this:

I wonder: Do I need a wallet to connect to that user? (I prefer not to use a wallet because sharing the wallet is not a good idea I guess)
How can I should configure the connection to USER01?

GRANT CREATE SESSION TO USER01;

I solved my problem by reading those blogs:
https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/securely-connecting-to-autonomous-db-without-a-wallet-using-tls
https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/post/connecting-your-autonomous-database-has-never-been-easier
In few words, I had to disable the mTLS (mutual TLS) protocol and enable TLS protocol. I configured also a Access control list with an CIDR block in my case.
